# How to use Windows Server 2008 as a Time Machine-style backup?

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008-r2, time-machine

Is there any way to setup Windows Server 2008 as a Time Machine-like backup device for my laptop?

Comment: What OS is your laptop?

Comment: Windows  7 Home Premium